Can random.sample handle the case k=0?
In code, can I assume:
assert random.sample((1,2,3), k=0) == []

I suspect the answer is yes, but I don't see explicit documentation confirming it.
I've got a case where k = desired_length - current_length is the number of extra random elements that I need to add to an existing list. I want to be certain that I don't need a special case to handle desired_length == current_length (the error case desired_length < current_length is already handled).

Why do you doubt it?

The documentation says that random.sample should "Return a k length list [...]", and you get as expected a 0-length list, so I don't see any problem here.

@nocomment: Because the Python documentation is incomplete. For instance, as your own answer states, k=-1 results in a ValueError but the documentation only says "If the sample size is larger than the population size, a ValueError is raised".

@MSalters But the documentation also doesn't explicitly talk about k=1, k=2, k=42 or k=632436867. Why are you asking about k=0? What's your reason?

@nocomment: k=42 clearly isn't an edge case. I had existing code dealing with desired_length < current_length and desired_length > current_length, and wondered about the edge case desired_length == current_length. So I checked the documentation to see if there was any restriction. The documentation states that the result is "in selection order", which presupposes that there is a selection. Other text is also slightly ambiguous, but I'm experienced enough to know how often documentation misses edge cases.

Ok, that's at least something. I  guess your everyday language usage is misleading you there, thinking that a selection of zero elements isn't a selection. But Python/math/compsci have no issue with that. You can also do sum([]), math.prod([]), all([]), math.comb(4, 0), or ask the combinatorial itertools for empty things. All work just fine, as they should.

@nocomment: That's nontrivial. For instance, the C++ equivalent of sum() is std::accumulate, and that needs a third parameter for the initial value precisely because it needs to return something for an empty range. functools.reduce() in Python does the same. In general, folds over empty lists are problematic.

Those request an initial value because otherwise they'd have no clue what to return, not even what type. That's not an issue here. Returning [] for k=0 is the obvious thing to do.

There's really no reason to doubt it, k=0 is a perfectly normal and reasonable number/argument. Unlike k=-1, for example, for which sample couldn't fulfill its documented promise to "Return a k length list".
It's intentional and tested, saying allowable range of 0 <= k <= N, testing two cases with k=0, and also testing that k=-1 raises an error (which also says ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative):
    def test_sample(self):
        # For the entire allowable range of 0 <= k <= N, validate that
        # the sample is of the correct length and contains only unique items
        N = 100
        population = range(N)
        for k in range(N+1):
            s = self.gen.sample(population, k)
            self.assertEqual(len(s), k)
            uniq = set(s)
            self.assertEqual(len(uniq), k)
            self.assertTrue(uniq <= set(population))
        self.assertEqual(self.gen.sample([], 0), [])  # test edge case N==k==0
        # Exception raised if size of sample exceeds that of population
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, self.gen.sample, population, N+1)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, self.gen.sample, [], -1)


Documentation states that:

Return a k length list of unique elements chosen from the population sequence.

So it is expected to return a 0 length list.
The code below return a 0 length list as stated in documentation.
import random
assert random.sample((1,2,3), k=0) == []
random.sample((1,2,3), k=0)

https://python-fiddle.com/saved/MkQtCxYBKHYIG2kJCSQc?run=true
